# Inserting semicolon in between data in a cell in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, string

I have data in column A, C, E and G. I want column I to hold all of the data from these separated by semicolons, I have searched the web but all I find is how to replace line breaks with semicolons and that doesn't do it. Below are the 3 pieces of code I have attempted to work into it

```
Range("I" & i).Value = "=A" & i & Chr(59) & "&" & "C" & i & "&" & "E" & i & "&" & "G" & i
Range("I" & i).Value = "=A" & i & "&C" & i & "&E" & i & "&G" & i
Range("I" & i).Value = Range("A" & i).Value + ; + Range("C" & i).Value + ; + Range("E" & i).Value + ; + Range("G" & i).Value
```

The second line comes closest to what I want but when I add & ";" into it I get errors.

Any ideas thoroughly appreciated

SOLVED : This was solved by an answer below, I had managed my own fix which I will detail but the accepted answer is a cleaner, more efficient way

mystring = "=A" & i & "&" & Chr(34) & ";" & Chr(34) & "& C" & i & "&" & Chr(34) & ";" & Chr(34) & "& E" & i & "&" & Chr(34) & ";" & Chr(34) & "& G" & i
    Range("I" & i).Value = mystring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `"&"";"""`.

In detail, you should use something like

```
"=A" & i & "&"";""" & "&C" & i
```

which result in

```
=A1&";"&C1
```

suppose `i = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
=CONCATENATE(A1, ";", C1, ";", E1, ";", G1)
```

Using VBA

```
Range("A2").FORMULA = REPLACE("=CONCATENATE(A1, ';', C1, ';', E1, ';', G1)", "'", CHR(34))
```

Comment: this is not available in VBA, even through Application.Worksheetfunction

Comment: I have marked the correct answer but would like to thank you also for attempting to answer my question, so thank you